# Unity 3d app on Google TV / Google TV Emulator: Missing Mono

Tags: android, android-emulator, unity-game-engine, google-tv

I'm trying to run a Unity built android app on Google TV. I've tried various things without much luck yet. Directly pushing the .apk built by unity on to the Google TV emulator doesn't work. I've also tried getting the code from unity's Temp/StagingArea folder and bringing that to Eclipse (in Ubuntu) and running it with the emulator (following this) but this doesn't work either. The guide works if you run the app on an AVD other than the Google TV emulator.

I've tried different settings from Unity (even different versions of Unity, namely Unity 3.4.1 and Unity 3.5).

With Unity 3.5, I've done a test with the following settings Android SDK version = 3.0 Device Filter = x86 and Armv6 with VFP (tried both) Graphics Level = OpenGL ES 2.0 Optimization = .NET 2.0 Subset Stripping Level = Disabled The scene simply has a camera and a sphere rendered in front of it

Both report the following error in the logcat:

```
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't     load mono: findLibrary returned null
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.BinexSolutions.gtvTest.SphereFromunity35Activity.onCreate(SphereFromunity35Activity.java:11)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1732)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1016)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4083)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-24 11:09:51.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Similar results for Unity 3.4.1. The Google tv emulator fails to run the app but other android emulators succeed.

### Unity 3.4.1 - Emulator build - Android SDK 2.3.3

Google TV Emulator = failed (failed to load mono: findlibrary returned null)

Android 2.3.3 emulator = works with (MinSDK = 10 = android 2.3.3)

### Unity 3.4.1 - ArmV6 build - Android SDK 2.3.3

Google TV Emulator = failed (no debug/error msg on console) (Expected since GTV is Intel-Atom x86)

Android 2.3.3 emulator = works with MinSDK = 10 = android 2.3.3)

Any clues about this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Unity requires the NDK which is not available for Google TV.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the underlying issue. On a side-note: Are there any 3d engines out there that don't depend on the NDK?

Comment: Your probably better off looking for that again, and / or asking w/ #Android #Game-Engine tags.

Comment: Also, is there any way I can statically link the mono library for x86 with my app so that it may run on GoogleTV ?

Comment: No - if it says x86 it probably needs the NDK.